# From what game does the following music come from?

Tags: game-identification

I love classical music and a few days ago during a road trip with a friend, the following song came on playing on his mp3 player in the car :

- [Mega download](https://mega.co.nz/#!MMFRnBAL!kjgampp_9myBh_hJrx6u3IwkT_E8PlUEQOhZtDZir2Q)
- [DropBox download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv7zo4uyb6fellt/Video%20Game%20Orchestra.mp3)

Unfortunately the song is labelled "Video Game Orchestra" since all my friend remember about it is that it comes from a video game that he used to play several years ago. I clearly recall hearing this song while playing but I can't remember from what game. I would love to find the game in order to see if it contains other great musics such as this one, can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game you are looking for is Super Smash Bros. Melee for the Nintendo Gamecube. That specific song appears on the [Fountain of Dreams stage](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Dream_Land:_Fountain_of_Dreams).

Comment: That's it. I didn't remember playing any Kirby game so Gourmet race seemed odd but smash bros melee definetly yes ! Thanks a lot, bring back old memories =)